# In what order does pdfbox parse a pdf file? (suppose there are more than 1 column in a page)

Tags: java, apache-poi, pdfbox

If there are 2 columns on a page of a pdf file, does pdfbox parse it column-wise or line by line?

Comment: Question's title and body say two different things.... Please be more specific.

Comment: The structure of pdf files is well-documented, and the logical way of parsing a file is "start at the beginning". The problem is that the order of things in the pdf file may have very little to do with how it appears on a page. How was your PDF file generated?

Comment: The pdf contains just 2 columns, but the first column is parsed after the parsing the second one.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "parse a PDF file", I assume you mean *apply text extraction* to it. In that case of PDFBox that would usually be by means of the `PDFTextStripper` class.

In that case the answer is "it depends".

- By default the `PDFTextStripper` extracts in the order of the text drawing instructions in the content streams. Quite often this corresponds to the logical order of content because PDF generators usually have input arranged in that order and generate output accordingly, e.g. multiple columns often will be extracted column-wise.

  BUT there is no guarantee for that; the text drawing instructions may theoretically be in any order; for example first all 'a's on a page may be drawn, then all 'b's, ...

  Such chaos is very seldom. But if the content of a PDF contains both fixed and dynamic contents, you might often first see the fixed, then the dynamic contents in the extracted text. For example first labels like "First Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", ... and then the values.
- Alternatively you can use `PDFTextStripper.setSortByPosition` to set the `SortByPosition` property to `true`. In this case PDFBox ignores the order of drawing and attempts to extract the PDF text line-by-line.